# Display tags number of an html page in another one

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a noob and this is for a school prject, I used `document.getElementByTagName("tagName").length;` to get the number of a specific tag in an html page, I need to display the result in another html page, How can I simply do that using javaScript

Comment: please show the code you have so far. are you using `sessionStorage` for persistence?

Comment: How can I do that my code so far is: <script> var x =document.getElementByTagName("myTag").length</script> it's returning the exact number of myTag in the same html page, I want to display this x in another html page

Comment: @SaidDanteAlegri I added a JavaScript only solution to do this to my answer.

Comment: Please be sure to select one of the answers if it helped solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The total count of all the tags in a page can be found like this:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('*').length;
```

The total count of all the specific tags (by name) can be found like this:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('title').length;
```

Here is a JavaScript-only (client-side) solution:

==Page 1==

```
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

var titleLength = document.getElementsByTagName('title').length;
createCookie('titleLength', titleLength, 1);
```

==Page 2==

```
function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}
var titleLength = readCookie('titleLength');
document.write(titleLength);
```

Here is a PHP-only (server-side) solution:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($HTML); // this is the path to your html file
$allElements = $dom->getElementsByTagName('title');
echo $allElements->length;
```

Comment: Yes how can I store that number to display it in another html page,

Comment: The `echo` part in the PHP example will open the file, count the number of tags, and output the number to a different page.

Answer (score 0):

on initial page load you'd get the number of tags you want to count

`var x = document.getElementByTagName("myTag").length`

then you'd need some sort of persistence such as html5 sessionStorage

`sessionStorage.setItem('count', x);`

Then once you are on the new page via a link etc, you get the value back from sessionStorage with:

`var theCount = sessionStorage.getItem('count');`

the variable `theCount` then stores the value from the previous page, this can then be used on the new page

Answer (score 0):

To *simply* do this in JavaScript, just carry a hash over and read it back.

The first HMTL pagex, name it whatever you like (index.html etc.):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Look how I count things</title>
</head>

<body>
<p>p tag</p>
<p>p tag</p>
<p>p tag</p>
<p>p tag</p>
<p>p tag</p>
<p>p tag</p>
<script>
document.addEventListener("click", function(){
    window.location = "secondpage.html#"+document.getElementsByTagName('p').length;
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Name your second html page secondpage.html and have it write out its own hash tag.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Look how I counted things</title>
</head>

<body>
<script>
    document.write(location.hash + " tags found");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: work as a charm, all of your suggestions, I went with Radio's way because it doesn't mess a lot with the architecture, thank you all